# Data from Formlayout do not get saved in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, blur, dhtmlx, form-layout

I am using CodeIgniter and DHTMLX to build my system. When my site first loads it show the DHTMLXGrid with all the data from the DB. And when I click on a record and press edit button, it will show the Formlayout.

In my form first field is description and then a checkbox which will enable few other select boxes. If i didn't change the checkbox status data won't get save in the DB. I have no idea what is wrong in my code. I am new to this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

workbench.js

```
if(buttonid=='save') { 

    eval(formSaveCallback);

    myFormbar.validate();

    if (defFrmSaveHandling) {

       dhxLayout.cells('b').collapse();

       search.grid.updateFromXML(search.grid.xmlLoader.filePath,true,true);

    }
}
```

datalibrary.js

```
function Save(){

    addForm.send(layoutBench.formDataUrl+'add/', "post", function(loader, response){ 

       if (debug) console.log('Save return code is :-',response);

       if(response==1) {

            $('#info').fadeIn();

            $('#info').html('Data is saved successfully');    

            $('#info').fadeOut(3000);

       } 
   });
}
```

My controller and model works fine. I think the issue is  because of the blur is not fired when I do not click on any other controls after adding the description may be if I can give a delay and enable the save buton it will work. But I don't no how to do that.
Any help regarding the matter?
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up withe the answer to this.
It is that I have to call the blur function at the beginning of the save function.

```
function Save(){

     addForm.getInput("description").blur();
     //rest of the code

}
```